# HTML,CSS - 100% div height on every device not working

Tags: css, html, height

I have some problems with html and css. I want 100% DIV's under each other but everythin i do is not working. It works almost but not on every mobile divece. It is working on my desktop but when i open it on my phone it is not working. Can some one please help me?

```js
window.onload = onLoad;

function onLoad()
{
 var teller = 0;
 //ONLOAD
 $('span').fadeIn(4000);
 $('html,body').animate({
   scrollTop: $('html').offset().top
 }, 1700);
 
 //MENU 
 $('#menu').on('click', function (e) 
 {
  $("#menuBar").animate({width:'toggle'},350);
  $("#menu").toggleClass('rotated');
 });
 //BUTTON_ONClICK
 //BUTTON_1
 $('#screen-1-go').on('click', function (e) 
 {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('html,body').animate({
   scrollTop: $('#screen-2').offset().top
  }, 1700);
    });
 
 //TO_SCREEN_3
 $('.more').on('click', function (e) 
 {
  teller=0;
  e.preventDefault();
  $('html,body').animate({
   scrollTop: $('#screen-3').offset().top
  }, 1700);
    });
 //TO_THE_TOP
 $('.top').on('click', function (e) 
 {
  teller=0;
  e.preventDefault();
  $('html,body').animate({
   scrollTop: $('html').offset().top
  }, 1700);
    });
 
 
 //VARS_SCROLL_EVENT
 var screens = ["html", "#screen-2", "#screen-3"];
 $('html').on('wheel', function(event) 
 {
  if (event.originalEvent.deltaY > 0) 
  {
   teller++;
   animateToDiv(screens[teller]);
  } 
  else 
  {
   teller--;
   animateToDiv(screens[teller]);
  }
 });
}

function animateToDiv(div)
{
 $('html,body').animate({
  scrollTop: $(div).offset().top
 }, 1700);
}
```

```css
html
 {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body 
{
 margin: 0;
 background: #000; 
 overflow-x: hidden;
 overflow-y: hidden;
}

/* Menu */
#menu
{
 position: fixed;
 right: 10px;
 z-index: 9999;
 cursor: pointery
}

#menu > img
{
 width: 60px;
 height: 60px;
}

#menuBar
{
 position: fixed;
 right: 0px;
 float: right;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: black;
 box-shadow: -1px 0px 1px 1px black;
 display: none;
 z-index: 9998;
 -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=70)";
 filter: alpha(opacity=70);
 -moz-opacity: 0.7;
 -khtml-opacity: 0.7;
 opacity: 0.7;
}

.rotated 
{ 
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}

/* Screen_1 */

#screen-1 
{ 
 position: fixed;
 font-family: Agenda-Light, Agenda Light, Agenda, Arial Narrow, sans-serif;
 background: url(../Uploads/Video/screen1-video.gif) repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 color: white;
 font-size: 1.2rem;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

#screen-1-tekst
{
 margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
 margin-top: 16em;
 width: 30em;
}

#screen-1-tekst > span
{
 font-family: 'Brush Script MT', cursive;
 text-shadow: -2px 0 black, 0 2px black, 2px 0 black, 0 -2px black;
 color: #DBBC90;
 font-size: 6em;
 display: none;
}

#screen-1-go
{
 margin-top: 16%;
}

.button
{
 display: block;
    font-size: 14px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.75);
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0.75);
    height: 45px;
    line-height: 48px;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: color 0.5s ease,border-color 0.5s ease;
    transition: color 0.5s ease,border-color 0.5s ease;
 margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 13em;
 margin: auto;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0; bottom: 10%; right: 0;
}

/* Screen2 */

#screen-2
{
 position: absolute;
 margin-top: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: #d55a49;
}

#screen-2-tekst > h1 
{
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 6em;
    line-height: 1em;
 color: rgba(99, 35, 35, 0.8);
    text-shadow: 1px 4px 6px #D55A49, 0 0 0 #000, 2px 4px 6px #D55A49;
 font-size: 5em;
 text-align: center;
}

#screen-2-tekst
{
 margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
 margin-top: 4em;
 width: 27em;
}

::-moz-selection { background: #5af; color: #fff; text-shadow: none; }
::selection { background: #5af; color: #fff; text-shadow: none; }

/* Screen2 */

#screen-3
{
 position: absolute;
 margin-top: 150.5%;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: #80a5ba;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Files/CSS/home.css">
  <script src="Files/JS/background.js"></script>
  <script src="Files/JS/JQBA.js"></script>
  <script src="Files/JS/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="menu">
   <img src="Files/Uploads/Image/hamburger.png">
  </div>
  <div id="menuBar">
  </div>
  
  <div id="screen-1">
   <div id="screen-1-tekst">
    <span>Joost de Niet</span>
   </div>
   <div id="screen-1-go">
    <h1 class="button">More about me</h1>
   </div>
  </div>
  
  <div id="screen-2">
   <div id="screen-2-tekst">
    <h1>Portfolio</h1>
   </div>
   <div id="screen-button">
    <h1 class="button more">More..</h1>
   </div>
  </div>
  
  <div id="screen-3">
   <div id="screen-button">
    <h1 class="button top">To the top</h1>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you please tell on what device you facing issue. if you attach screenshot that will help or give link to check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 height: 100vh
```

is the one of solution for responsive designs
or u should use mediaquery

Answer (score 1):

You should try using height:100vh for mobile devices

Answer (score 1):

You can use `vh` for this. [Read more here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp).

So it will be something like

```
div {
    height: 100vh /*100% of device height*/
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Glad it helped. Please accept one of the answers so as not to leave any open questions hanging around SO :)